# IBM Worklight server

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I have a question regarding how to install worklight server on top of websphere application server in unix environment.
I have a worklight project war file and I have to deploy this war file in websphere server.

Comment: Did you try to use Google? https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc%2Fadmin%2Ft_installing_wl_server_into_was_nd.html

Answer (score 0):

As Gas mentioned, your answer is found online. Because WebSphere is Java-based, the instructions are likely to be the same no matter the operating system used. You should follow the instructions provided in the IBM Worklight Knowledge Center.

Assuming you are running the latest IBM Worklight 6.2.0.01 release, you can read the instructions here: [Installing Worklight Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_installation.html)

Comment: Thanks Idan..
In windows machine we have IBM Installation manager but in unix we dont have Intallation manager. We have to use commands for installation of worklight server. And i dont have a worklight repository fot installation manager. I have tried to download it from IBM Passport library site but they were asking the site number and business justification.

Comment: If you are an IBM customer, you should have those.

Comment: You can find Installation Manager download links here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27025142. As @IdanAdar says, if you are a licensed IBM customer, you should have a site number. If you can't find it, please contact your local IBM commercial rep who should be able to resolve your issue.